# How can I perform an operation after that some time (a fraction of second) is passed in JQuery\JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-timing

I have to perform an operation after a delay time (a fraction of a second).

Actually I have this code section:

```
$("thead.opening").click(function () {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    alert("INTO second function, chrome: " + is_chrome);

    $(this).next().css('width', '10000000em');
    $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');

});
```

What I need to do is replace this alert():

```
alert("INTO second function, chrome: " + is_chrome);
```

with an operation that wait some time.

How can I do it?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure javascript function setTimeout

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    //Execute the code to be run
  }, 1000);
```

final Solution

```
$("thead.opening").click(function () {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;


    setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
        //Execute the code to be run
    $(this).next().css('width', '10000000em');
    $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
      }, 1000);


});
```

Comment: The problem is that no operation have to be performed, it only have to wait and then perform the next operation in my previous example. Can you show me how have I to modify my previous code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Use a timeout; in javascript you can use setTimeout to:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

Like:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
var $myNext=$(this).next();

if (is_chrome) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
         $myNext.css({width: '10000000em', display: 'table-row-group'});
    }, 1000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4pxedhzd/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this seems like a copy-paste from the MDN. Might not really help the asker since it doesn't clearly connect to the question.
Edit: Saw you just edited the post to look a lot more "grounded" in the question :) Disregard my comment.

Comment: @FabianMiiro yep, I have improved the answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
alert("INTO second function, chrome: " + is_chrome);
```

with

```
if(is_chrome) {
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).next().css({'width':'10000000em', 'display':'table-row-group'});
    }, 1000);
}
```

This will run the function after 1000 milliseconds (=1 second). You have to set `that = this` because `this` has another context in the function.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0eajx8sv/

Comment: I will try but I don't wan't that anything is printed

Comment: I don't understand :) If you don't want the alert to be displayed just remove it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a typical "wait" in the middle of your code I would suggest using callbacks since that's what JavaScript uses normally.

I would suggest using the "setTimeout" function to make the JavaScript call wait some specific time before doing the next things. Here's how it could be used in your scenario:

```
$("thead.opening").click(function () {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    setTimout(waitedCall(), millisecondsToWait);
});

//This function will now be called after "millisecondsToWait" ms. And then execute the rest of the code
function waitedCall()
{
    $(this).next().css('width', '10000000em');
    $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
}
```